# For loops with Jinja

Tags: python, html, for-loop, jinja2

[[my html image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3Olq.png)][[my python image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N8Sc.png)]

Im trying to itterate through the names in my database and add them to a dropdown menu on my site but the dropdown doesn't display anything. Where am I going wrong?

[my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEmN5.png)

I was expecting this to be a dropdown of all the names in my datatbase when I clicked on it but there is nothing in the dropdown

Comment: Please don't share code snippets as screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

In your Python code, you are utilizing list comprehension to extract names using `[row["name"] for row in savedevents]`. This results in a list of names, such as `["name_1", "name_2"]`.

However, in your HTML code, you are attempting to access it with the syntax `{{ row["name"] }}`. Instead, it would be more appropriate to use `{{ row }}` since you are passing only a list, not a queryset.